# Function Interpreter that returns Func<double[],double>

Tags: c#, parsing, math

I was using a math function interpreter Jace.NET. Here's a good example of how to work with it:

```
CalculationEngine engine = new CalculationEngine();
Func<double, double, double> formula = (Func<double, double, double>)engine.Function("x1+2/(3*x2)")
.Parameter("x1", DataType.FloatingPoint)
.Parameter("x2", DataType.FloatingPoint)
.Result(DataType.FloatingPoint)
.Build();
```

But another library (that I have to use) demands `Func<double[],double>` as input, not `Func<double,double,double>` or `Func<double,double,double,double>` that Jace can return

So i need is an interpreter that can make a function that takes an array of double as input and returns a value, so basically this:

```
Func<double[],double> formula = ...
```

I've tried to make this in Jace, but had no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Since you know the number and types of arguments at compile time, would simply doing `Func<double[], double> convertedFormula = arr => formula((int)arr[0], arr[1]);` work?

Comment: @user5090812 that works! I actually don't know the amount of variables at compile time, but it can be solved with a switch. Thank you! You should add an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the nice things about lambda expressions is that they are so easy to use to create delegate instances, and can do the exact same kind of parameter mapping that you could do with a regular method.

If you have, for example, an API you need to call and which you pass a `Func<double[], double>`, but what you actually have at hand is a `Func<double, double, double>` (for example), you could do this with a named method in a special class:

```
class FuncMapper
{
    private readonly Func<double, double, double> _func;

    public FuncMapper(Func<double, double, double> func)
    {
        _func = func;
    }

    public double M(double[] input)
    {
        return _func(input[0], input[1]);
    }
}
```

Used like:

```
Func<double[], double> formula = new FuncMapper(jaceFunc).M;
```

But that's fairly verbose. With a lambda expression, you can make the compiler do most of the work:

```
Func<double[], double> formula = array => jaceFunc(array[0], array[1]);
```

Do beware of if and how variable capturing occurs. The lambda expression will capture `jaceFunc` according to its scope; if it's a local and remains unchanged after the lambda expression, then it will also remain unchanged in the lambda expression. But if you capture a variable with a broader lifetime and it is modified before the lambda's delegate is invoked, the lambda expression will use the *modified* value of the variable. What's being captured is the variable, not its value.

**Notes:**

- Your specific scenario involves a dynamically created delegate (e.g. `jaceFunc` above), but of course the same thing would work with a named method as well.
- The above shows just a single scenario, i.e. two input parameters, while you say that you might have more than two. You can address this as you have (i.e. by using a `switch` or similar), or you could write an `Expression`-building method that does essentially the above but takes into account the number of parameters of the called method and generates the necessary array element lookups and passes them to the invoked delegate or method.
  For just a few scenarios, the `switch` is much easier, but if you have a need to generalize over different parameter types and method signature variations, an `Expression`-based approach would likely be more useful in the long run.